# Django inlineformset instance vs queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been trying to get a handle on Django inlineformsets. What's been tripping me up is trying to pass in a queryset into the formset constructor.

Consider two simple models.

```
class PickSheet(Model):
    name = Models.CharField()

class Pick(Model):
    picksheet = Models.ForeignKey(PickSheet, related_name='picks')
    team = Models.CharField()
    points = Models.CharField()
```

Now create a FormSet.

```
PickFormSet = inlineformset_factory(PickSheet, Pick, max_num=5, extra=0, fields=['team', 'points'])
```

In the database, I have a PickSheet created with two Picks.

If I use instance= when creating the formset, I get the expected two forms.

```
obj = get_object_or_404(PickSheet, id=3)
formset = PickFormSet(instance=obj)
print(formset.management_form)
```

If I use queryset= when creating the formset, I get zero forms.

```
qs = PickSheet.objects.filter(id=3)
formset = PickFormSet(queryset=qs)
print(formset.management_form)
```

What's going on? Isn't PickSheet.objects.filter(id=3) equivalent to PickSheet.objects.get(id=3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PickSheet.objects.filter(id=3)` is not equivalent to `PickSheet.objects.get(id=3)` since `PickSheet.objects.filter(id=3)` is return a list and `PickSheet.objects.get(id=3`) will return an object instance.